# FLEX - BitmapImage not updated after filters assigned

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air

I've a flex mobile project and a component (as-Class) inside of it with an BitmapImage, a Button and a Graphic sign.

When a boolean is false the button is disabled, the image gets gray through a ColorMatrixFilter (bitmapImage.filters = [myCMFilter]) and the sign appers, else button is enabled, the image has no filters (bitmapImage.filters = []).

The problem is that the image doesn't switch to grey -> but the sign appears and the button gets disabled.

If call the setting of the filters one frame later (callLater -> a function setting the filters) everything works.

I have extracted the code to a sample project and everything works... without callLater

Anyone an idea what can happpen in my case???

Christian

Code:

```
package de.xxx.yyy.app.view.componentsV2.widgets 
{
    import de.assets.header.HeaderBGDarkGray;
    import de.assets.miscellaneous.StarGrey;
    import de.assets.miscellaneous.StarYellow;
    import de.assets.miscellaneous.UnderConstruction;
    import de.assets.ImageAssets;
    import de.xxx.yyy.app.view.componentsV2.buttons.BasicButton;
    import de.xxx.yyy.app.view.pools.UserInterfaceComponentsPool;

    import flash.debugger.enterDebugger;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;

    import mx.core.IVisualElement;

    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    import spark.components.Button;
    import spark.components.Group;
    import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;
    import spark.primitives.BitmapImage;

    public class StadiumWidget extends Group{

        private static var STADION_LEVELS:int = 7;

        private static var SIDE_SPACING:int = 7;
        private static var BUTTON_WIDTH:int = 150;
        private static var BUTTON_HEIGHT:int = 33;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // USER INTERFACE COMPONENTS
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private var underConstructionImage:UnderConstruction;
        private var currentImage:BitmapImage;

        private var footerBackground:HeaderBGDarkGray;
        private var developButton:BasicButton;
        private var manageButton:BasicButton;

        private var displayedlevel:int;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // FIELDS
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private var createdStars:Array = [];

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private var _grayscaleFilter:ColorMatrixFilter;

        public function get grayscaleFilter():ColorMatrixFilter
        {
            if(!_grayscaleFilter)
            {
                var matrix:Array = [0.3, 0.59, 0.11, 0, 0,
                    0.3, 0.59, 0.11, 0, 0,
                    0.3, 0.59, 0.11, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0];

                _grayscaleFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix);
            }
            return _grayscaleFilter;
        }

        public function set grayscaleFilter(value:ColorMatrixFilter):void
        {
            _grayscaleFilter = value;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // GETTER AND SETTER WITH DIRTY FLAG
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private var levelChanged:Boolean;
        private var _level:int;

        public function set level(value:int):void
        {
            _level = value;
            levelChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
            invalidateDisplayList()
        }

        public function get level():int
        {
            return _level;
        }

        //

        private var isUnderConstructionChanged:Boolean;
        private var _isUnderConstruction:Boolean;

        public function set isUnderConstruction(value:Boolean):void
        {
            _isUnderConstruction = value;
            isUnderConstructionChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
            invalidateDisplayList()
        }

        public function get isUnderConstruction():Boolean
        {
            return _isUnderConstruction;
        }


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public function Stadium()
        {
            super();
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // LIFECYCLE STANDARD METHODS
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        var testSprite:UIComponent;

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            currentImage = new BitmapImage();
            currentImage.smooth = true;
            currentImage.percentWidth = 100;
            currentImage.scaleMode = "letterbox";
            addElement(currentImage);

            // FOOTER

            footerBackground = new HeaderBGDarkGray();
            addElement(footerBackground);

            developButton = new BasicButton();
            developButton.width = BUTTON_WIDTH;
            developButton.height = 38;
            developButton.x = SIDE_SPACING;
            developButton.label = resourceManager.getString("FlexApp", "stadium.developButtonLabel");
            developButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleDevelopButtonClicked);
            addElement(developButton);

            manageButton = new BasicButton();
            manageButton.width = BUTTON_WIDTH;
            manageButton.height = 38;
            manageButton.label = resourceManager.getString("FlexApp", "stadium.manageButtonLabel");
            manageButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleManageButtonClicked);
            addElement(manageButton);

        }

        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            if(currentImage && levelChanged)
            {
                setcurrentImage();
                setStars();
                levelChanged = false;
            }

            if(isUnderConstructionChanged)
            {
                setUnderConstruction();
                isUnderConstructionChanged = false;
            }
        }

        override protected function measure():void
        {
            super.measure();
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var FOOTER_HEIGHT:int = footerBackground.getPreferredBoundsHeight();
            var STAR_X_STEP:int = 25;

            footerBackground.y = unscaledHeight - FOOTER_HEIGHT;
            footerBackground.width = unscaledWidth;

            manageButton.x = unscaledWidth - (BUTTON_WIDTH + SIDE_SPACING);
            manageButton.y = developButton.y = footerBackground.y + ((FOOTER_HEIGHT - BUTTON_HEIGHT) / 2);

            if(currentImage.height > unscaledHeight - footerBackground.height)
            {
                currentImage.height = unscaledHeight - footerBackground.height;
            }

            if(underConstructionImage)
            {
                underConstructionImage.x = (unscaledWidth - underConstructionImage.width) / 2;
            }

            var starStartX:int = unscaledWidth / 2 - (STADION_LEVELS * STAR_X_STEP) / 2;
            var starY:int = createdStars.length > 0 ? unscaledHeight - FOOTER_HEIGHT + (FOOTER_HEIGHT - createdStars[0].height) / 2 : 0;

            for(var i:int = 0; i < createdStars.length; i++)
            {
                createdStars[i].y = starY;
                createdStars[i].x = starStartX + i * STAR_X_STEP;
            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // HELPER METHODS
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private function setStars():void
        {

            var pool:UserInterfaceComponentsPool = UserInterfaceComponentsPool.getInstance();
            var star:IVisualElement;

            while(createdStars.length > 0)
            {
                star = createdStars.pop() as IVisualElement;
                if(containsElement(star))
                {
                    removeElement(star);
                }
                pool.disposeUserInterfaceComponent(star);
            }

            // POOL THE STARS!!!

            for(var i:int = 1; i <= STADION_LEVELS; i++)
            {
                if(i <= level)
                {
                    star = pool.getYellowStar();
                }
                else
                {
                    star = pool.getGreyStar();
                }
                addElement(star)
                createdStars.push(star);
            }
        }

        private function setcurrentImage():void
        {
            if(level != displayedlevel)
            {
                currentImage.source = currentImages["LEVEL_" + level + "_NAME"];
                displayedlevel = level;
            }
            setUnderConstruction();
        }

        private function setUnderConstruction():void
        {

            developButton.enabled = isUnderConstruction == false;

            if(isUnderConstruction)
            {
                if(!underConstructionImage)
                {
                    underConstructionImage = new UnderConstruction();
                    underConstructionImage.y = 30;
                    underConstructionImage.width = 330;
                    underConstructionImage.height = 330;
                    addElement(underConstructionImage);
                }
                callLater(setFilters, [true]);
            }
            else
            {
                callLater(setFilters, [false]);
                if(underConstructionImage && containsElement(underConstructionImage))
                {
                    removeElement(underConstructionImage);
                }
                underConstructionImage = null;
            }
        }

        private function setFilters(value:Boolean):void
        {
            if(value && (!currentImage.filters || currentImage.filters.length == 0))
            {
                currentImage.filters = [grayscaleFilter];
            }
            else if(!value && currentImage.filters && currentImage.filters.length > 0)
            {
                currentImage.filters = [];
            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // EVENT HANDLER
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private function handleDevelopButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event("openlevelPopup", true));
        }

        private function handleManageButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event("openManagePopup", true));
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // DISPOSE
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public function dispose():void
        {
            developButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleDevelopButtonClicked);
            manageButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleManageButtonClicked);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: It's just a timing issue. In your real application, the component is probably nested a few more levels deeper in a component hierarchy. This generally means there are more cycles of things being invalidated and re-rendered when the boolean changes. People used to diss `callLater()` and I avoided it. It's not that bad, as long as you don't get carried away. Sometimes I've found there's nothing else you can do. If it doesn't cause other issues that the user can perceive, I wouldn't worry. If you're still worried, show the code you're using and give us an idea of what that hierarchy looks like.

Comment: PS: If you've built a custom component that executes Flex life cycle methods, it's possible that you've gone astray somewhere... It's always good to show your code on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I took a peek at your code, I didn't notice anything wrong. Nice job w/implementing the component life cycle :) Perhaps the problem is as I alluded to.